# Ubuntu Server 22.04 Autoinstall and Cloud-Init Not Executing Commands

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

I am trying to set up an Ubuntu Server 22.04 installation using autoinstall and cloud-init. I have two USB keys (I followed this tutorial https://www.jimangel.io/posts/automate-ubuntu-22-04-lts-bare-metal/):

- One with an ISO image of Ubuntu Server 22.04 with autoinstall enabled.
- The second one contains two YAML files: `meta-data` (empty file) and `user-data`.

When I try to install the new setup on a machine, ubuntu gets installed, the user is created **but** when the computer reboots, none of the packages (see user-data) seem to be installed. Even simple tests like creating a directory using runcmd do not persist.

**Debugging Attempts**

Checked cloud-init logs at /var/log/cloud-init.log and /var/log/cloud-init-output.log but did not find any relevant errors or warnings.
Tried simplifying the user-data file to just create a directory, but it did not work.

I'd appreciate any pointers to debug and resolve this issue.

Here is my user-data file:

```
#cloud-config
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true

autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US
  keyboard:
    layout: fr
  identity:
    hostname: user
    username: user
    password: "$6$xyz$waX2p...."
  ssh:
    install-server: true
  packages:
    - openssh-server
  package_upgrade: true
  late-commands:
    - shutdown -h now
runcmd:
  - apt install -y curl autossh unzip
  - apt install -y docker.io
  - systemctl start docker
  - systemctl enable docker
  - mkdir /home/bob
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to include the `runcmd` within the autoinstall, like that:

```
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true

autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US
  keyboard:
    layout: fr
  identity:
    hostname: user
    username: user
    password: "$6$xyz$waX2p...."
  ssh:
    install-server: true
  packages:
    - openssh-server
  package_upgrade: true
  late-commands:
    - shutdown -h now
  runcmd:
    - apt install -y curl
```